# Photoelectrons could be detected in position space rather than momentum space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect, laser-interaction

In experiments, to study the interaction between atoms and light, experimenters use lasers ( i.e. coherent light) that interact with a gas of atoms. This treatment is pure statistics. To be more specific, let's consider, an experiment that aims to detect ejected electrons from atoms under laser forces.

**My question:**  Electrons detection could be in position space? and why their detection are considered in momentum space in many experiments?

Comment: Having used a position sensitive multichannel plate detector to measure electrons from multi-photon ionization events, I would have to say yes you can. Now, what you really want is the spatial distribution of those events to get back to the scattering parameters, which often are discussed in terms of momentum space. (I'm not sure really how to measure electrons in momentum space directly, actually).

Comment: In momentum space measurement, they use VMI (velocity map imaging) using a multichannel plate detector that can store the position of the electron when it hits the plate and its corresponding velocity (then momentum).   Thank you, I will read about the position-sensitive MCP detector.

Comment: Sure, but that is still a real space measurement, if you get what I mean. Detectors have a real space position, so even if you measure energy as well it is an energy/momentum at a given point (or points). Yes, picky, I know...

Comment: If I got it, the position where the momentum is measured is a real space position. But the angular distribution in momentum space in a specific projection could be produced by these experiments and fit well  with quantum mechanical calculations which is surprising......